# what happens when pool of stateless beans runs out

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, java-ee-5, stateless-session-bean

we know that the stateless sessions beans (JEE5 context) can be pooled. 
I was wondering what happens when the Server's pool of stateless session beans has no more instances left and another client request comes in...

a) Is the client request put in a (blocked) waiting state  OR

b) the server refuses the connection right away.. OR

c) Can we handle this situation programmatically to give a customized response based on the SLA of our specific application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies from vendor to vendor.  WebSphere Application Server will create new instances as required, and it will remove beans when returning them to the pool if the pool has reached its maximum size.  The product also can be configured to have a hard limit using the [poolSize](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/rejb_ecnt.html) option that causes requests to block until a bean becomes available.

Comment: Great... thanks for your response.. I found some similar options for my server (weblogic in this case)... just putting them here for anybody else who might have the same question

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/ejb/session.html#wp1132096